# javascript regex for ip address with asterisk masking

Tags: javascript, regex, ip-address

I would like to make a regular expression for an IP address with asterisk(*)
which matches these below:

*The digit 127.0 could be any number between 0 to 255.*

```
**[TRUE]**
127.*.*.*
127.0.*.*
127.0.0.*

**[FALSE]**
127.*.*.1
127.*.0.1
127.0.*.1
```

What I have made until now is...and of course, failed to make it out.
I totally got lost..

```
_regex = function(value) {
    var _match = /^(?:(\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))\.(?:(\*|\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))\.(\*|(?:\d{1,2}(?:.\d{1,3}?)))\.(\*|(?:\d{1,3}(?:\*?)))$
    if(_match.test(value)){
        //do something;
    }
}
```

If you give me any chance to learn this, would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `var re = (?` Regular expression literals need delimiters.

Comment: if(re.match(re)){ is wrong, use this if(value.match(re)){

Comment: @ CertainPerformance @ÁlvaroTouzón Sorry for my mistake. I didn't copy my script and rushed to write this, so made many mistakes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a negative look ahead to make sure no number follows an asterisk.

Like so: `(\*(?!.*\d))`

working example:

```js
var ips = [
  '127.*.*.*',
  '127.0.*.*',
  '127.0.0.*',
  '127.*.*.1',
  '127.*.0.1',
  '127.0.*.1'
];

var regex = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|(\*(?!.*\d)))(\.|$)){4}$/;

for(var i = 0; i < ips.length; i++){
  console.log(ips[i] + ': ' + regex.test(ips[i]));
}
```